# How does recursion evaluate in type theory

Tags: type-theory

The primitives of types in type theory are `Void`, `Unit`, product types, sum types, and function types, where these things stand for, respectively, 0, 1, multiplication, addition, and exponentiation.

So, e.g. `Bool` has a value of 2, because it has two possible representations (`True` or `False`), similarly `Ordering` has a value of 3.
A function `Bool -> Ordering` is 3^2 which is 9, so there are 9 possible functions that could inhabit the type `Bool -> Ordering`.

A map is very similar to a function. I feel like this should be represented in in type theory somehow.

A map could be defined as `data Map k v = Empty | Entry k v (Map k v)`.
Now going from `Map Bool Ordering`, this would evaluate to: $1 + (2 \cdot 3 \cdot ??)$.

I don't really know how to express recursive types in this fashion. If it is $map = 1 + (2 \cdot 3 \cdot map)$, is there some way to illustrate the similarities between `Function` and `Map` types?

Comment: There are an infinite number of values of type `Map k v` even if `k` and `v` are finite (as long as they are inhabited).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correspondance of types to numerals in this way is a rather handwavey affair outside of finite types, so the correct answer to your question is: infinite.

Now of course that's rather boring. In some specific cases we can still work with these values, though the degree to which it helps us isn't all that high. For a number of types, similar to the map you've proposed above (or standard lists), they can be represented as power series, including this map here.

Your type corresponds to an infinite sum $\sum_0^\infty 6^i$ in some sense, but this isn't a valid power series, and there's little sense we can make out of an infinite sum this way. One nice solution is to add a term for the level of indirection, so that it's a correct power series $\sum_0^\infty 6^i x^i$. This is about the best we can do to assign a value (in a non-useless way), by expanding our domain of definition from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}((x))$.

To give you a bit more of what you're possibly looking for, we can consider it as a power series over $\mathbb{C}$ instead. For a few equations, we can use proofs with complex numbers, which we can carry back. So in this case, the series converges to $-\frac{1}{5}$ (as a standard geometric series). This is the origin of the famous "Seven Trees in One", and there's a good exposition on the generalizability in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212377). You may also want to take a look at [another paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0004133) with some generalizations of the concept you're using here. You may also be interested in combinatorial species, for which there are a few standard resources, and which use power series for similar counting arguments (with symmetry). They're part of the structure types mentioned in the second paper. The book *Combinatorial Species and Tree-Like Structures* is a good exposition if you can find a copy of it.